# How to print 10 letters preceding every occurrence of a particular character?

Tags: perl, bash, grep

Using `grep`, I can print all occurrences of the uppercase letter "Z" in my document. The output, however, will display the entire lines in which every "Z" in the document was found. I need to limit this to printing only the 10 letters appearing before every occurance of "Z".

E.g., if the document has a line with "AAAABBBBBBBBBCCCCCCDDDDDDDZ", it will print "CCDDDDDDD", the 10 letters appearing before.

- If there are fewer than 10 letters prior to "Z", then nothing needs to be printed.
- If "Z" appears multiple times in a single line, the 10 letters preceding each of these "Z"'s should be printed, e.g.: "AAAABBBBBBBBBZCCCCCDDDDDDDZ" will print "ABBBBBBBBB" and "CCDDDDDDDZ".

The result will be an output list of these letters, e.g.:

```
ABBBBBBBBB
CCDDDDDDDZ
```

How can I print the 10 letters preceding every occurrence of the letter "Z" in my document?

Comment: What do you want to get from `AAAABBBBBBBBBZDDDDDDDZ`?

Answer (score 9):

Simple:

```
grep -oP '.{10}(?=Z)' <<< AAAABBBBBBBBBZCCCCCDDDDDDDZ
```

Explanation:

```
-o     : Print only match, not entire line
-P     : Use PCRE / Perl regex
.{10}  : Match is any 10 characters,
(?=z)  : which are followed by "Z". (Search for positive look-ahead for more details)
<<< ...: Here string
```

EDIT:

NOTE: This does not work, if the 10 characters we want are overlapping. e.g. input=AAAABBBBBBBBBZDDDDDDDZ. If the input contains such pattern, see [igegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774404/793796)

Comment: Not clear whether that's a requirement IMHO. If so, the regex from your answer should work with `grep -oP` as well, I imagine.

Comment: No, my pattern would only print `Z` if used with `grep -oP` (if it works at all).

Comment: Nit: You mean it's not clear if the OP stated the requirement correctly. There's no doubt that "*If "Z" appears multiple times in a single line, the 10 letters preceding each of these "Z"'s should be printed*" is a requirement, and that your code doesn't always meet it.

Comment: Hmm.. I agree. It does fail at this corner case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -nE'say for /(?<=(.{10}))Z/g' <<'__EOI__'
AAAABBBBBBBBBZCCCCCDDDDDDDZ
AAAABBBBBBBBBZDDDDDDDZ
__EOI__
ABBBBBBBBB
CCCDDDDDDD
ABBBBBBBBB
BBZDDDDDDD
```

or

```
$ perl -nE'say for /(?=(.{10})Z)/g' <<'__EOI__'
AAAABBBBBBBBBZCCCCCDDDDDDDZ
AAAABBBBBBBBBZDDDDDDDZ
__EOI__
ABBBBBBBBB
CCCDDDDDDD
ABBBBBBBBB
BBZDDDDDDD
```

Comment: +1. I am new to using perl. Can you explain the code? I was surprised that `.{10}` is in lookahead/lookback.

Comment: I just have a sec right now, so I can just explain why quickly: If you want overlapping matches, then the match can't consume the characters, so the match must be in a lookahead/lookbehind.