# Searching a string pattern in grep for a sliding window

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have written code for searching and counting the number of string occurrences using `grep`. But, It is not taking into account the sliding window.

Tried:

```
grep -E -o "(A|B){2}" datafile | sort | uniq -c
```

datafile:

```
AABBABAABBBA
```

Output:

```
2 AA
1 AB
1 BA
2 BB
```

Expected output:

```
2 AA
3 BA
3 AB
2 BB
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `3 BB`?

Comment: So the output need not be sorted in any manor?

Answer (score 1):

how about,

```
for i in {"AA","AB","BA","BB"}; do echo "AABBABAABBBA" | grep -o $i; done | sort | uniq -c
```

I think it's not simple.

anyway... It returns the outpt what you want!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=""}{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) 
            print $(i-1) $i}' datafile | grep -Eo "[AB]{2}" | sort | uniq -c
2 AA
3 AB
3 BA
3 BB
```

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
$ echo AABBABAABBBA | perl -nE 'say for /(?<=([AB]{2}))/g' | sort | uniq -c
    2 AA
    3 AB
    3 BA
    3 BB
```

Note: Above solution is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774404/793796)...

Answer (score 1):

If using `bash` version 4.0 or newer, you could use an associative array to keep track of each unique set of two characters and their count:

```
declare -A list
while read -r line; do
    for ((i=0;i<=$((${#line}-2));i++)); do
        ref="${line:$i:2}"
        if [[ ${!list[@]} != *"$ref"* ]]; then
            list["$ref"]=1
        else
            ((list["$ref"]++))
        fi
    done
done < file
for index in "${!list[@]}"; do
    echo "${list[$index]} $index"
done
```

Output:

```
3 AB
2 AA
3 BB
3 BA
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect the output to be as you show? Break it down:

```
$ echo AABBABAABBBA | grep -E -o "(A|B){2}"
AA
BB
AB
AA
BB
BA
```

Now `sort`:

```
$ echo AABBABAABBBA | grep -E -o "(A|B){2}" | sort
AA
AA
AB
BA
BB
BB
```

**Note:** `AB` occurs before `BA` following sort. Now find `uniq`:

```
$ echo AABBABAABBBA | grep -E -o "(A|B){2}" | sort | uniq -c
    2 AA
    1 AB
    1 BA
    2 BB
```

`AB` will always `sort` before `BA` (unless reversed). If you reverse the `sort` you will invert the entire answer.

To create your sliding widow, you can just walk down the string:

```
str=AABBABAABBBA; for ((i=0; i<$((${#str}-1)); i++)); do \
printf "%s\n" "${str:$i:2}"; done | sort | uniq -c
```

**output:**

```
  2 AA
  3 AB
  3 BA
  3 BB
```

Or as suggested by jaypal:

```
echo "AABBABAABBBA" | awk -v FS= \
'{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)a[$i,$(i+1)]++}END{for(x in a) print a[x],x}'

2 AA
3 AB
3 BA
3 BB
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to recurse for every two chars in the string. So `AABBABAABBBA` should output `AA, AB, BB, BA ... etc` and then count `em.

Comment: Oh..., the `{2}` saying to match the preceding expression exactly `2` times along with the `-o` won't do that. It just grabs the `2` char matches working its way down the string putting each match on a separate line. I'll take another look given your input.

Comment: Sure, I was thinking along the lines `echo "AABBABAABBBA" | awk -v FS= '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)a[$i,$(i+1)]++}END{for(x in a) print a[x],x}'` but I was put off my OP's lack of attempt in drafting a good question. `:)`

Comment: No matter how you slice it, you are still going to come up with the same `AA AB BA BB`. `( str=AABBABAABBBA; for ((i=0; i<$((${#str}-1)); i++)); do printf "%s\n" "${str:$i:2}"; done | sort | uniq -c )`

Answer (score 0):

**Bash solution:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read str
do
   len=$(echo "${#str}")
   i=0
   #Convert the string in to array
   ar=($(while [[ "$len" -gt "$i" ]];do echo "${str:i:1}";let "i = $i + 1";done))
   k=0
   #iterate through array and print the string for piping it into grep
   for ((j=0;j<${#ar[@]};j++))
   do
      k=$((k = j+1))
      [ "$k" -lt "$len" ] && echo "${ar[j]}${ar[k]}"
   done
done < datafile > datafile1
grep -hoP '\b\w+\b' < datafile1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl way:

```
$ echo AABBABAABBBA | 
    perl -F"" -alne 'for($i=0;$i<$#F;$i++){$k{$F[$i].$F[$i+1]}++}
                     print "$_ : $k{$_}" for keys(%k); '
AA : 2
BB : 3
AB : 3
BA : 3
```

#### Explanation

The `-F` sets the field delimiter to the empty string and the `-an` causes  each input line to be split on the value of `-F` into the `@F` array. The result is an array where each element is a single letter of the input. We then create a hash whose keys are each set of 2 consecutive letters (`$F[$i] . $F[$i+1]`) and then increment the corresponding value each time a two letter combination is found. Finally, the keys and their values are printed in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Bash solution

```
str="AABBABAABBBA"
for i in `seq 1 ${#str}`; do
   echo $str | cut -c${i}-
done | grep -Eo '^(A|B){2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The for loop builds all shorter tail substrings of the original string

```
AABBABAABBBA
ABBABAABBBA
BBABAABBBA
BABAABBBA
ABAABBBA
BAABBBA
AABBBA
ABBBA
BBBA
BBA
BA
A
```